# singly linked list python code

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, linked-list

I have recently tried converting a singly linked list from a C program into my own python program. I have tested the code myself but I am still unsure if the program has been converted properly. I would like someone to peer review my code to see if there are any errors in methodology, too many methods, any missing methods, etc.

I have tried implementing some of my own singly linked list operations based from the advice from this website: https://afteracademy.com/blog/types-of-linked-list-and-operation-on-linked-list

The original C Program: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/ammoffat/ppsaa/c/listops.c

My own python code:

```
class Node():
        
    # Node for a single linked list
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        


class LinkedList():

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.foot = None

    def length(self):

        '''Returns the length of a linked list.'''

        current_node = self.head
        node_total = 0
        while (current_node != None):
            node_total += 1
            current_node = current_node.next
        return node_total

    def is_empty_list(self):

        '''Checks if a linked list is empty.'''

        return self.head == None

    def stack_insert(self, data):

        '''Inserts a node at the HEAD of the list;
           LIFO (Last In, First Out).'''

        new_node = Node(data)
        # Makes new_node.next point to next node (defualt None if 1st insertion)
        new_node.next = self.head
        # Makes the HEAD of linked list point to new node
        self.head = new_node

        if (self.foot == None):
            # First insertion into linked list; node becomes HEAD & FOOT
            self.foot = new_node

    def queue_append(self, data):

        '''Appends a node at the FOOT of the list;
           FIFO (First In, First Out).'''

        new_node = Node(data)
        
        if (self.head == None):
            # First insertion into linked list; node becomes HEAD & FOOT
            self.head = self.foot = new_node
        
        else:
            # Makes the original last node point to the newly appended node
            self.foot.next = new_node
            # Makes the newly appended list as the official FOOT of the linked list
            self.foot = new_node

    def insert_after(self, data, index):

        '''Inserts a NEW node AFTER a specific node indicated by index.'''

        # Need to ensure provided index is within range
        if (index < 0):
            print("ERROR: 'insert_after' Index cannot be negative!")
            return
        elif (index > (self.length() -1)):
            print("ERROR: 'insert_after' Index exceeds linked list range!")
            return

        # Use stack_insert to insert as first item
        elif (self.is_empty_list()) or (index == 0):
            self.stack_insert(data)
            return

        # Use queue_insert to append as last item
        elif (index == (self.length() -1)):
            self.queue_append(data)
            return

        new_node = Node(data)
        prior_node = self.head
        current_node = self.head
        search_index = 0
        
        # Keep traversering through nodes until desired node
        while (search_index != index):
            prior_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next
            search_index += 1
        
        # Makes prior node is point to target node
        prior_node = current_node
        # Makes current node point to the node AFTER target node (default None of last node)
        current_node = current_node.next

        # Makes target node point to newly added node
        prior_node.next = new_node
        # Makes newly added node point to original node that WAS AFTER target node
        new_node.next = current_node


    def delete_head(self):

        '''Deletes the HEAD node.'''

        # Linked list is empty
        if self.is_empty_list():
            return

        old_head = self.head
        # Adjusts the head pointer to step past original HEAD
        self.head = self.head.next

        if (self.head == None):
            # The only node just got deleted
            self.foot = None

    def delete_foot(self):

        '''Deletes the FOOT node.'''

        # Linked list is empty
        if self.is_empty_list():
            return

        old_foot = self.foot
        prior_node = self.head
        current_node = self.head

        # Need to keep cycling until final node is reached
        while (current_node.next != None):
            prior_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next
        
        # Adjust newly FOOT node to point to nothing
        prior_node.next = None
        # Makes linked list forget about original FOOT node
        self.foot = prior_node

    def delete_node(self, index):

        '''Deletes a target node via index.'''

        # Linked list is empty
        if self.is_empty_list():
            return

        # Need to ensure index is within proper range
        elif (index < 0):
            print("ERROR: 'delete_node' Index cannot be negative!")
            return
        elif (index > (self.length() -1)):
            print("ERROR: 'delete_node' Index exceeds linked list range")
            return
        
        prior_node = self.head
        current_node = self.head
        search_index = 0

        # Keep travsersing though nodes until desired node
        while (search_index != index):
            prior_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next
            search_index += 1

        # Adjusts node PRIOR to target node to point to the node the AFTER target node
        prior_node.next = current_node.next

    def update_node(self, new_data, index):

        '''Updates target node data via index.'''

        # Linked list is empty
        if self.is_empty_list():
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Linked list is empty; no node data to update!")
            return
        
        # Need to ensure index is within proper range
        elif (index < 0):
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Index cannot be negative!")
            return
        elif (index > (self.length() -1)):
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Index exceeds linked list range!")

        current_node = self.head
        search_index = 0

        # Keep traversing through nodes until desired node
        while (search_index != index):
            current_node = current_node.next
            search_index += 1

        # Can now change data
        current_node.data = new_data

    def get_node_data(self, index):

        '''Extracts that data from a specific node via index.'''

        # Linked list is empty
        if self.is_empty_list():
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Linked list is empty; no node data to update!")
            return
        
        # Need to ensure index is within proper range
        elif (index < 0):
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Index cannot be negative!")
            return
        elif (index > (self.length() -1)):
            print("ERROR: 'update_node' Index exceeds linked list range!")

        # Index matches HEAD or FOOT
        if (index == 0):
            return self.head.data
        elif (index == (self.length() -1)):
            return self.foot.data
        
        current_node = self.head
        search_index = 0

        # Keep traversing though nodes until desired node
        while (search_index != index):
            current_node = current_node.next
            search_index += 1
        
        return current_node.data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks un-Pythonic because you are using methods like `length` rather dunder methods like `__len__`.

### Node

Before that we can change `Node` to use [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). `dataclasses` will automatically give your class some boiler-plate, like `__init__` and `__repr__`. To use `dataclasses.dataclass` you need to type your class. To type attributes we can use `attr: type`.

```py
from typing import Any

class Node:
    data: Any
    next: "Node"
    # ...
```

There are two important parts to note;

- you should try not to use `Any` as doing so destroys type information.
  Here we can instead use [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) and [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic). And
- we have encased the type `Node` in a string. Before Python 3.10 type annotations are eagerly evaluated. Since we're using the name `Node` before `Node` has been assigned, if we didn't the type would fail to resolve.
  We can use `from __future__ import annotations` to make Python use lazy evalutaion automatically from Python 3.7+.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Node(Generic[T]):
    data: T
    next: Node
    # ...
```

We can now change the class to use `dataclasses.dataclass`. Since we want to be able to not provide `next` in the `__init__` we can assign `None` to `next`, so that `next` defaults to `None` if nothing is provided.

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Node(Generic[T]):
    data: T
    next: Node = None

ll = Node(0, Node(1))  # example usage
print(ll)
```

```
Node(data=0, next=Node(data=1, next=None))
```

The nice output helps makes debugging much easier as now we can just print `self.head` (in the `LinkedList`) to be able to visually debug any incorrect states. The default `__repr__` also automatically handles recursion, to aide in debugging.

```py
ll.next.next = ll
print(ll)
```

```
Node(data=0, next=Node(data=1, next=...))
```

**Note**: `...` just means there is recursion here, we would get the same output if we assigned `ll.next` rather than `ll`.

### Linked List

#### Iterating

> ```py
> def length(self):
>     '''Returns the length of a linked list.'''
>     current_node = self.head
>     node_total = 0
>     while (current_node != None):
>         node_total += 1
>         current_node = current_node.next
>     return node_total
> ```

There are some ways `length` is not Pythonic:

- > [For consistency, always use `"""triple double quotes"""` around docstrings.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)
- You should use `is` when comparing to singletons like `None`.
- Please don't use unneeded parentheses.

  ```py
  while current_node is not None:
  ```
- Your method's name should be `__len__` as then you can use `len(obj)` rather than `obj.length()`. Doing so can help make `LinkedList` a drop in replacement for say `list`.
- I would define a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to iterate through the linked list. Using a generator function can make your code much simpler. We can then use standard iterator parts of Python like `for` and `sum` instead.

```py
def __iter__(self):
    curr = self.head
    while curr is not None:
        yield curr.data
        curr = curr.next

def __len__(self):
    """Returns the length of a linked list."""
    return sum(1 for _ in self)
```

#### Inserting

Rather than defaulting `head`, and `foot`, to `None` we can default to `Node(None)`.
We can then make your code simpler by getting rid of all the `if self.head is None` code.

```py
def queue_append(self, data):
    self.foot.next = Node(data)
    self.foot = self.foot.next
```

**Note**: If you do add a default head then you'd need to change `__iter__` to not return the default head. However we wouldn't need to change `__len__`, because `__len__` is based off `__iter__`!

Inserting into the head would also stay simple. The changes we made to `Node` can also make the code simpler.

```py
def stack_insert(self, data):
    self.head.next = Node(data, self.head.next)
    if self.foot is self.head:
        self.foot = self.head.next
```

There are some change I'd make to `insert_after`:

- Rather than using `stack_insert` and `queue_append`, the code would be far simpler built from scratch.
- Since `length`, or `__len__`, has to iterate through the linked list, calling the function isn't too helpful.
- Any performance gain from `queue_append` is lost by using `length`.
- By calling `stack_insert` with an input of 0 your code is prone to making bugs.

  ```py
  ll = LinkedList()
  ll.queue_append("a")
  ll.insert_after("b", 0)
  ll.insert_after("c", 1)
  print(ll.head)
  ```

  ```
  Node(data='b', next=Node(data='a', next=Node(data='c', next=None)))
  ```
- Now that the linked list will always have a root `Node` we can easily change the function to insert before, rather than after.
- You should `raise` errors not print.

In all I'd follow [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

```py
def insert(self, index, value):
    if index < 0:
        raise IndexError("cannot work with negative indexes")
    curr = self.head
    for _ in range(index):
        curr = curr.next
        if curr is None:
            raise IndexError(f"index, {index}, is out of range")
    curr.next = Node(value, curr.next)
    if curr is self.foot:
        self.foot = curr.next
```

Now `stack_insert` looks quite unneeded; we can just use `LinkedList.insert(0, ...)` instead.
Also if we changed `__len__` to return from a constant then we could change the code so there is no appreciable gain from `queue_append`.

#### Deleting

Rather than falling for the same problems as insert we should just ignore `delete_head` and `delete_foot`.

Since the code for finding the current node, or previous node for delete, is exactly the same, we can make a function to return a desired node.

```py
def _index(self, index):
    if index < 0:
        raise IndexError("cannot work with negative indexes")
    curr = self.head
    for _ in range(index):
        curr = curr.next
        if curr is None:
            raise IndexError(f"index, {index}, is out of range")
    return curr
```

Now we just need to ensure the *next* value is is not `None` as the index would be out of range. And ensure we update `self.foot`.

```py
def delete_node(self, index):
    prev = self._index(index)
    if prev.next is None:
        raise IndexError(f"index, {index}, is out of range")
    if prev.next is self.foot:
        self.foot = prev
    prev.next = prev.next.next
```

#### Getting / Updating

There should be no suprise. We just call `self._index` and handle the node however is needed.

#### Pythonisms

- We can use the [container dunder methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types):

  - `get_node_data` -> [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)
  - `update_node` -> [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)
  - `delete_node` -> [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__)
- A common Python idiom is negative numbers mean 'go from the end'.
  We can easily change `_index` to handle negatives rather than error.
- You should rename `is_empty_list` to [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) to allow truthy testing your linked list.
- You should mimic the names of existing datatypes, like [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) or [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). **Note**: you should *not* mimic the names of [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue); both classes are used for a different pattern than your code is for.

  - `stack_insert` -> `appendleft`.
  - `queue_append` -> `append`.
  - `delete_head` -> `popleft`.
  - `delete_foot` -> `pop`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Node(Generic[T]):
    data: T
    next: Node = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.foot = Node(None)
        self._length = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        curr = self.head.next
        while curr is not None:
            yield curr

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.head.next is None

    # You don't need max if you don't want to make a doubly
    # linked list with a foot node like the head node
    def _norm_index(self, index, min=0, max=0):
        index += min if 0 <= index else max
        index = len(self) + 1 + index if index < 0 else index
        if index < min:
            raise IndexError("out of range min")
        if len(self) + max < index:
            raise IndexError("out of range max")
        return index

    def _index(self, index, min=0, max=0):
        try:
            _index = self._norm_index(index, min, max)
            if _index == len(self):
                return self.foot
            curr = self.head
            for _ in range(_index):
                curr = curr.next
                if curr is None:
                    raise IndexError("curr is None")
            return curr
        except IndexError as e:
            raise IndexError(f"index, {index}, is out of range").with_traceback(e.__traceback__) from None

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._index(index, min=1).data

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        curr = self._index(index, min=1)
        curr.data = value

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        prev = self._index(index - 1 if index < 0 else index)
        if prev.next is None:
            raise IndexError(f"index, {index}, is out of range")
        if prev.next is self.foot:
            self.foot = prev
        self._length -= 1
        prev.next = prev.next.next

    def insert(self, index, value):
        curr = self._index(index)
        self._length += 1
        curr.next = Node(value, curr.next)
        if curr is self.foot:
            self.foot = curr.next

    def append(self, value):
        self.insert(-1, value)

    def appendleft(self, value):
        self.insert(0, value)

    def pop(self):
        del self[-1]

    def popleft(self):
        del self[0]
```

Comment: May I kindly check why `TypeVar('T')` is better than `Any`? I am unsure how to use `TypeVar('T')` properly here.

Comment: @nan Take `list`, you can provide a type for the objects inside - `a: list[str]`. This tells us we have a list of strings. From here we can then know using `" ".join(a)` would work, where `b: list[int]` would fail. As `str.join` only accepts joining strings. `Any` means we wouldn't know if the data in the list is a `str` or an `int`, meaning we can't be sure whether or not `" ".join` will work. As `list[Any]` can contain strings, integers, well anything.

Comment: Ah got it, now I am busy changing all my codes from `Any` to `Generic`, as I can already see why it is useful in type hinting. Thanks!

Comment: @nan Happy to help! :) One thing to note, from my understanding tools like `mypy` assume you will be slowly moving from a large untyped project to a typed one. This means a lot of the checks are turned off by default. Because no-one likes seeing errors in the thousands to hundreds of thousands. If you use these tools to help find possible bugs then you'll want to check for a `--strict` mode. When I got over the learning curve with `--strict` Python's `typing` system has become very simple and second nature to use.

Comment: Yes `mypy` is painful sometimes, especially when I use `tuple([10, 10, 10])`, it refuses to treat it as `Tuple[int, int, int]` for example.